# jQuery: jquery form plugin syntax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-plugins

I'm using jquery with the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). 
I read through a bunch of posts, the docs, etc., and I'm still having trouble with what I believe to be simple. I have a form with some simple text inputs and a couple textareas, and I have this link that I want to trigger submission of that form to a specific method (/email):

```
<a id="email-data">Send Email</a>
```

and this jquery in doc ready:

```
$('#email-data').click(function() {
    var options = {
        url: '/email/',
        success: alert('Email sent.')
    };
    $('#report-giftcard-sales-form').ajaxSubmit(options);   
});
```

So I would expect it to submit to my /email method, but no such luck. Currently I just have the /email method logging a debug message, so it's as simple as can be.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does 'Email sent.' alert message displays after submiting form?

Comment: @antyrat: Sorry, should've mentioned that, yes, it alerts properly.

Comment: Maybe your rewrite rule does not recognize last slash at the url? Did you try to set url: '/email', ?

Comment: @antyrat: no, rewrite rule is ok, I can trigger method by going to it directly in my browser via URL: http://localhost/email/

Comment: I think I got it. I was loading jquery.form.js before jquery.js in my <head>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here...

Hey stupid, yes you (a.k.a. me), you need to load jquery BEFORE you load a jquery plugin!

(I of course know this. Sometimes stupidity just happens when you're working too fast)

Good Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Callback from `success` option can't be alert because it require more than one param at the callback function. You need to write something like this:

```
$('#email-data').click(function() {
    var options = {
        url: '/email/',
        success: formSended
    };
    $('#report-giftcard-sales-form').ajaxSubmit(options);   
});
function formSended(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
  alert('Email sent.Status: '+statusText);
}
```

Comment: @antyrat: yes, i've tried that way as well. I don't get the alert, and the method doesn't post. I know it's not a syntax error because other js on page is fine.

Comment: when I add the +statusText to the alert message, it is 'undefined'

Comment: You add statusText inside callback function to the alert or at the options to the alert? Do you have live example?

Comment: I add statusText inside callback function by copying your example. I don't have live, sorry :(

It's definitely not hitting the /email method.

Comment: Do you use firebug or other JS debugger?

Comment: Yes, I now see: "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined - jquery.form.js:11"

Comment: I also see: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'ajaxSubmit' - site.js:14"